# Corona SDK login to facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coronasdk

I want to post a message to facebook from Corona SDK application,but it all the time fails to login.
My steps:

```
1. I have generated key for my Android app: app name is "myapp.APK", package name is com.myapp (http://corona.techority.com/2011/09/24/how-to-generate-a-key-for-your-android-app/)
2. I have selected "Native Android App" in facebook and filled in folowing: 
"Android Package Name": com.myapp
"Android Class Name": com.myapp.activity
"Android Key Hash": key hash which I have generated in step 1.
"Configured for Android SSO": Enabled
```

My mobile app is exact copy from: http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/facebook
P.S. I have entered valid App ID and App Secret.
But still getting Login failed :((

Did I miss something? Don`t know what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was wrong.
The problem was, that for some reason Android App Hash was not matching the key in Facebook Android App Hash field, therefore I was receivind error:" Your key does not match allowed keys in application settings"
SOLUTION: I have changed the hash in Facebook to the hash key, which was in error message. Now it works fine.